# firebase Cloud Json API using API KEY

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to explore `Cloud Storage JSON API V1`, as mentioned in request, the GET request can be called with a `key`, I have tried many keys, I have created in credentials panel, but I am only getting `keyInvalid` or any other error, I want to know about this key, which API key Google Cloud Storage is using here

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/wearableeot-39e6a.appspot.com?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Thanks for help, I only want to know about this API Key.

Comment: If you API Key is `abcd-efgh-ijkl`, you should concatenate it this way `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/wearableeot-39e6a.appspot.com?key=abcd-efgh-ijkl`. The rest is explained in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the instructions you find here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey

In a nutshell, you should:

1. Go to the Credentials page in the Google Cloud Platform Console (not the Firebase console), for your project.
2. Click the "Create Credentials" drop-down box and choose "API key": you get the key in a dialog box.
3. Possibly restrict the key. See more infos [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en)